# How to get rate this app link to your iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I am making a simple iPhone App. I need to get the link to rate that app. I am not getting how to get that link.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
    NSString *rateAppURL = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=APPLE_ID&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rateAppURL]];
```

you can get APPLE_ID from [itunesconnect.](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)

You need to go to your application information where application identifier Apple Id is provided.

Hope it helps you.